# High DPI setting causes Firefox to not render scrollbar arrows in Select box

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, dpi

I'm running Firefox 4 on Windows 7 with a DPI setting of 144 dpi.  I have a web page with a 3rd party datepicker that has a select boxes for the Month and Year fields.  The problem is that Firefox will not render the up/down arrows, so the user cannot select a date.

I have taken the month select box out of the datepicker and isolated the problem. In the screenshot below, Firefox (left) does not show up/down arrows for size:2 and size:3.  IE (right) shows them correctly.

[image: screenshot of Firefox vs IE showing DPI problem]

HTML code for the select box with size:2:

`<select size="2"><option>January</option><option>February</option><option>March</option><option>April</option><option>May</option><option>June</option><option>July</option><option>August</option><option>September</option><option>October</option><option>November</option><option>December</option></select>`

I could modify the datepicker to use a different size (1 or 4) or use a lower DPI, but it may not be an option for some of my users.  Any ideas ... if not a fix, then a cause...?

Comment: it will work fine for 96 and 120 dpi because those are the standards. Anything else and you should expect failure.

Comment: 96 dpi is the standard, but shouldn't the failure should be consistent across browsers?  Usually, Firefox is the _less_ problematic browser but not in this case.

Comment: it all depends on the apps. I'd expect firefox to be rubbish at this. I'd expect only IE to work well at very high dpi. If anything else works well then that would be a bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what you would expect when you leave the safety and comfort of 96 or 120 DPI.

Although Microsoft have been nagging developers for years about high DPI, the standard of support for DPI > 120 is still depressingly poor.

Application developers need to do a lot of testing in order for their applications to work well at a wide range of DPI values.  I can see how it happens that applications fail at some DPI values and for a browser which renders all sorts of weird and wonderful content it must be even hard to come up with comprehensive tests.  All the same, this is clearly a bug in Firefox and you should submit a bug report and hope for the best!

---

As an aside, I recently performed some high DPI testing on my app and took at all the way up to 192 DPI.  The app worked a treat but it looked really weird.  Don't try this unless you've got a high resolution monitor because on a small monitor it can be hard to change the settings back to something more manageable!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Outside of Microsoft and now Android, there's been little mention of this issue.  My guess is most people don't even know it's a customizable setting.

Comment: [Firefox bug report filed - Bug #653030.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=653030)

Answer (score 0):

definitely a DPI issue. couldn't recreate it in FF or IE running 96dpi, changed to 144 and the scrollbars disappeared. you may have to tinker with this setting to see where it stops showing up.

Comment: I'd like to find out the acceptable DPI number, but don't have the patience for all the system restarts.  And it would not resolve the problem.